# jQuery DOM - Missing elements, lengths 0

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-append

Need some better understanding on DOM / Missing elements.

I use

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
// show div tag
});
```

But I seem to be stuck with my elements being somehow not available in the DOM.

```
console.log($(".show_quota").length);     
console.log($(".show_restriction").length);
```

Both lengths are 0. So these div tags are not in available in my DOM.

So what must I look for? 
How do I get these elements in the DOM? Any idea why these html form elements disappear of the DOM?

Doesn't `$(document).ready(function()` ensure all html elements appear in the dom? As long as the class and id are called correctly in jquery?

**Update 1:** Installed the Mozilla DOM Inspector - But overwhelmed by the info :)

But hey ... Looking at the good old source html ( via Inspect Element With Firebug) and the div tags dont show up... so ...no wonder the jquery commands dont work.

**Update 2:** The html markup is handled via;

```
    $('#modal').html("");

        var output = '<div class="modal-content">';
        output += 'some html stuff';
        output += '<div id="show_quota" >'; 
        output += 'some html stuff 2';
        output += '</div>'; 


    $('#modal').append(output);
    $('#modal').reveal();
```

**Update 3:** ISSUE SOLVED;

By;

1. Uninstalling FireQuery ( Buggy on my setup )
2. Modified

   ```
     output += '<div id="show_quota" >';    // to line below
     output += '<div id="show_quota" style="display:inline" >';
   ```
3. These made the tags appear / disappear when the checkboxes were clicked.

Comment: What does the `HTML` look like?

Comment: Well that's a very broad question. There's potentially an infinite number of reasons why the elements aren't in your DOM. Without knowing the specifics of your project, it's impossible to say. Are you trying to DOM-script the elements in? Are they missing from your HTML source code? Etc.

Comment: the best way to get those elements to be in your DOM, is to actually add them into your DOM.  ...and to make sure you use the selectors correctly. `.` is for class and `#` is for ID.

Comment: Noted. Will upload the html as well

Comment: @Banana - thanx for the reminder on the selectors. First thing I triple checked. The selectors/elements are in a html form - it contains some fields/ccheckboxes with a save button. The div tags are shown / hidden using jquery. I can get them to work in another area.  They show / hide properly.

Comment: Open developer console in your browser and try to select the elements using jquery, see if it returns anything.

Comment: @Banana - developer console meaning firebug yes? I have done that - using console.log heavily but I don't know how to use it to view the DOM and investigate why the div element is invisible to jquery

Comment: Usually if you right click an element and choose inspect element it will open the dom explorer, you can swotch to a console from that new window as well in all browsers i know. Type the selectors in the console manually, and see if it returns the elements.

Comment: Another thing, are those elements added dynamically? Ajax maybe? Because that will explain the behavior you are experiencing.

Comment: @Banana - the html form is done in a jquery modal dialog using $ modal.html whereby I output the html code using javasript as various output = '<div class = "show_quota" >'; etc, etc

Comment: Im not familiar with jquery modal (yet) but if it generates the elements dynamically then it would explain the behavior. You need to wait until the elements are created prior to manipulating them.

Comment: @Banana - isn't that the purpose of the document.ready function ?

Comment: No, document.ready waits until the hardcoded dom is rendered. Anything thats being added after that, using javascript, is something else.

Comment: @Banana - is showing / hiding div tags , disabling elements something outside the scope of document.ready ?

Comment: No its not. Its supposed to work fine. Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle/code snippet?

Comment: @Banana - Just installed the Mozilla DOM Inspector... checking this tool out ... i really need to know why my jquery elements are missing in the DOM

Comment: @Utkanos - Pls look at Update 2. There were missing from the html source code. Something to do with $('#modal').html("") ?

Comment: No - JavaScript has no connection with the source code sent from the server. JS deals only with the DOM, which is an interpreted, mutable, runtime manifestation of that source code. Please Google source code vs. DOM for more.

Comment: @Utkanos - Thanx. As per Update 3 Solved !

Answer (score 2):

Add something like this to the DOM...

```
<div class="show_quota"></div>
<div class="show_restriction"></div>
```

`class` is referenced with **.** and `id` is referenced with **#**

e.g. `<div id="show_restriction"></div>` would use `console.log($("#show_restriction").length);`

here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpyge21r/) if you need to test.

Comment: Are you referencing `jquery`?

Comment: the html/div and the jquery

Comment: Do you have the script tag on the page?

Comment: all the javasript / jquery is in filejs.php which have the <script> tag . Is this what u mean?

Comment: Thanx. As per Update 3 Solved !